# TS2488: Type 'string | null' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, iterator

I am trying to convert https://github.com/camwiegert/typical/blob/master/typical.js into TypeScript.

In Vanilla JS, it looks like:

## typical.js

```js
export async function type(node, ...args) {
    for (const arg of args) {
        switch (typeof arg) {
            case 'string':
                await edit(node, arg);
                break;
            case 'number':
                await wait(arg);
                break;
            case 'function':
                await arg(node, ...args);
                break;
            default:
                await arg;
        }
    }
}

async function edit(node, text) {
    const overlap = getOverlap(node.textContent, text);
    await perform(node, [...deleter(node.textContent, overlap), ...writer(text, overlap)]);
}

async function wait(ms) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function perform(node, edits, speed = 60) {
    for (const op of editor(edits)) {
        op(node);
        await wait(speed + speed * (Math.random() - 0.5));
    }
}

export function* editor(edits) {
    for (const edit of edits) {
        yield (node) => requestAnimationFrame(() => node.textContent = edit);
    }
}

export function* writer([...text], startIndex = 0, endIndex = text.length) {
    while (startIndex < endIndex) {
        yield text.slice(0, ++startIndex).join('');
    }
}

export function* deleter([...text], startIndex = 0, endIndex = text.length) {
    while (endIndex > startIndex) {
        yield text.slice(0, --endIndex).join('');
    }
}

export function getOverlap(start, [...end]) {
    return [...start, NaN].findIndex((char, i) => end[i] !== char);
}
```

And my TS conversion looks like:

## typical.ts

```
export async function type(node: HTMLElement, ...args: any[]): Promise<void> {
  for (const arg of args) {
    switch (typeof arg) {
      case 'string':
        await edit(node, arg);
        break;
      case 'number':
        await wait(arg);
        break;
      case 'function':
        await arg(node, ...args);
        break;
      default:
        await arg;
    }
  }
}

async function edit(node: HTMLElement, text: string): Promise<void> {
  const overlap = getOverlap(node.textContent, text);
  await perform(node, [
    ...deleter(node.textContent, overlap),
    ...writer(text, overlap),
  ]);
}

async function wait(ms: number): Promise<void> {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function perform(
  node: HTMLElement,
  edits: Iterable<string | null>,
  speed: number = 60
): Promise<void> {
  for (const op of editor(edits)) {
    op(node);
    await wait(speed + speed * (Math.random() - 0.5));
  }
}

export function* editor(
  edits: Iterable<string | null>
): Generator<(node: any) => number, void, unknown> {
  for (const edit of edits) {
    yield node => requestAnimationFrame(() => (node.textContent = edit));
  }
}

export function* writer(
  [...text]: string,
  startIndex: number = 0,
  endIndex: number = text.length
): Generator<string, void, unknown> {
  while (startIndex < endIndex) {
    yield text.slice(0, ++startIndex).join('');
  }
}

export function* deleter(
  [...text]: string | null,
  startIndex: number = 0,
  endIndex: number = text.length
): Generator<string, void, unknown> {
  while (endIndex > startIndex) {
    yield text.slice(0, --endIndex).join('');
  }
}

export function getOverlap(start: any, [...end]: Iterable<any>): number {
  return [...start, NaN].findIndex((char, i) => end[i] !== char);
}
```

Mostly, I followed VSCode's advice on hover to type it & some logic.

However, it gives me an error saying:

> typical.ts(61,3): semantic error TS2488: Type 'string | null' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

Line 61 is `deleter()` function's `[...text]`, i.e,:

```
[...text]: string | null,
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: @NikitaMadeev i already have it set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, `[...text]` argument from function `deleter` is actually an array of characters.
for example, consider this call `deleter(node.textContent, overlap)`.
type of `node.textContent` can be `string` or `null` and the argument type is `[...text]: string | null` but `textContent` can be `null` and you cannot destructure it to `[...text]`. There will be two paths.

1. `[...text] = node.textContent`
2. `[...text] = null`

The second one is invalid that's why you got this type error.
You may change the function to

```
export function* deleter(
  text: string | null,
  startIndex: number = 0
): Generator<string, void, unknown> {
  if (text === null) {
    yield ""// Or throw
    return
  }
  const [...chars] = text
  let endIndex = chars.length
  while (endIndex > startIndex) {
    yield chars.slice(0, --endIndex).join("");
  }
}
```

Update 1:
`Path was expected to have a container!` error can be resolved by adding curly braces `{...}` around the switch case body.
Like.

```
case 'string':
{
  await edit(node, arg);
}
break;
```

`unknown Statement of type "ForOfStatement"` error can be resolve by adding correct babel configs.
Here is the correct config.

```
//.babelrc.js
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "last 2 Chrome versions",
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-for-of",
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
      {
        helpers: false
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That did make sense. However, I got another error `Path was expected to have a container!` pointing near `switch`

Comment: In which line exactly?

Comment: The `switch` one.  Line no. 3 on the character `s`.

Comment: That is actually strange. The explicit type of arg is any.

Comment: Not sure I follow?

Comment: Could you please share an online editor URL with your code?
Here is my ts playground URL: https://preview.tinyurl.com/y52nejmr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218513/discussion-between-nidin-vinayakan-and-deadcoder0904).

Comment: @deadcoder0904 I updated the solution. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you so much, Nidin. This worked well. Although I got another error `(babel plugin) TypeError: /react-typical/src/typical.ts: Property name expected type of string but got null` which I'm trying to solve [here](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/react-typical). Lmk if u have any idea about this one. And thanks for all the help :)

Comment: It's because `--target node`. The compiler cannot decide whether node supports object destructuring. Add `"@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring"` to babel plugin to fix it.

Comment: Haa just was writing the comment. I did `const chars = Array.from(text);` instead & removed `target` equals `node` from `.babelrc` & `package.json` script :)